# What is Java using to output in console, and how can I capture it in ruby?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I am running IRB and I use the method mentioned here http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-60 to return the ruby version, it works fine.

```
irb(main):001:0> %x{ruby -v}
=> "ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]\n"
```

But when I try to do the same thing in IRB with Java, I can see it printing to screen but it does not return.

```
irb(main):002:0> %x{java -version}
java version "1.6.0_27"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_27-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.2-b06, mixed mode)
=> ""
```

What method is Java using to output to the console, and how can I capture it for use inside of a ruby/rails program?

Comment: I noticed that this is definitely not a ruby issue (not that you said it was).  Executing `java -version > test.txt` in bash results in the java info being printed to the screen and nothing going into `test.txt`.

Comment: I made the assumption that %x was capturing stdout, if that isn't the case what is it doing? It captures other commands like linux's %x{du -hs}, or more elaborately %x{bash -c "sudo vserver myserver exec ls"}
It would be save to say these things do not explicitly return things in a ruby-friendly format and it simply gets caught in stdout...

Comment: `%x` captures STDOUT only. The problem is the stream you want to capture isn't STDOUT, it's STDERR. See my answer how to deal with it simply. And, it's not a case of being Ruby-friendly, it's a case of needing to know how to work with the command-line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java is using STDERR to print its version information. You can capture that easily by routing STDERR to STDOUT's stream, and capturing both.

```
asdf = `java -version 2>&1`
puts asdf
```

will output:

```
java version "1.6.0_33"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_33-b03-424-10M3720)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.8-b03-424, mixed mode)
```

This is a very common technique when working at the command-line. Do a `man sh` at the command-line, and search for `REDIRECTION` using "`/REDIRECTION`" and read from there.

Comment: Great answer. Is there a way of marking a line that came from stderr instead of stdout?

Comment: Answeing my own question in comment, $?.exitstatus == 0 if success and == 1 if fail and == 127 if command not found

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "marking a line". You want to tell if the line was received from STDERR vs. STDOUT? You have to use `popen3` to differentiate between the two, because it captures both STDOUT and STDERR into different channels.